# Translate Objective - C Introduction to AudioUnits into Swift

Tags: ios, audiounit, avaudiosession, audiotoolbox

I alredy managed to translate this code so the render callback gets called:
http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/10/ios-tone-generator-introduction-to.html

I'm sure that my render callback method is not right implemented, because I either get no sound at all or I get pretty awful noise from my headphones.
I also don't see a connection between my audioSession in viewDidLoad and the rest of the code.

Is there anyone who can help me out with this?

```
private func performRender(
inRefCon: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>,
ioActionFlags: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioUnitRenderActionFlags>,
inTimeStamp: UnsafePointer<AudioTimeStamp>,
inBufNumber: UInt32,
inNumberFrames: UInt32,
ioData: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>) -> OSStatus
{

// get object
let vc = unsafeBitCast(inRefCon, ViewController.self)
print("callback")

let thetaIncrement = 2.0 * M_PI * vc.kFrequency / vc.kSampleRate
var theta = vc.theta

//    var sinValues = [Int32]()
let amplitude : Double = 0.25

let abl = UnsafeMutableAudioBufferListPointer(ioData)
    for buffer in abl
    {
        let val : Int32 = Int32((sin(theta) * amplitude))
    //        sinValues.append(val)
        theta += thetaIncrement

        memset(buffer.mData, val, Int(buffer.mDataByteSize))
    }

vc.theta = theta

return noErr
}

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
let kSampleRate : Float64 = 44100
let kFrequency : Double = 440
var theta : Double = 0

private var toneUnit = AudioUnit()
private let kInputBus = AudioUnitElement(1)
private let kOutputBus = AudioUnitElement(0)

@IBAction func tooglePlay(sender: UIButton)
{
    if(toneUnit != nil)
    {
        AudioOutputUnitStop(toneUnit)
        AudioUnitInitialize(toneUnit)
        AudioComponentInstanceDispose(toneUnit)
        toneUnit = nil
    }
    else
    {
        createToneUnit()
        var err = AudioUnitInitialize(toneUnit)
        assert(err == noErr, "error initializing audiounit!")
        err = AudioOutputUnitStart(toneUnit)
        assert(err == noErr, "error starting audiooutput unit!")      
    }
}

func createToneUnit()
{
    var defaultOutputDescription = AudioComponentDescription(
        componentType: kAudioUnitType_Output,
        componentSubType: kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO,
        componentManufacturer: kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple,
        componentFlags: 0,
        componentFlagsMask: 0)

    let defaultOutput = AudioComponentFindNext(nil,&defaultOutputDescription)


    let fourBytesPerFloat : UInt32 = 4
    let eightBitsPerByte : UInt32 = 8

    var err = AudioComponentInstanceNew(defaultOutput, &toneUnit)
    assert(err == noErr, "error setting audio component instance!")
    var input = AURenderCallbackStruct(inputProc: performRender,     inputProcRefCon: UnsafeMutablePointer(unsafeAddressOf(self)))

    err = AudioUnitSetProperty(toneUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback, kAudioUnitScope_Global, kOutputBus, &input, UInt32(sizeof(AURenderCallbackStruct)))
    assert(err == noErr, "error setting render callback!")

    var streamFormat = AudioStreamBasicDescription(
        mSampleRate: kSampleRate,
        mFormatID: kAudioFormatLinearPCM,
        mFormatFlags: kAudioFormatFlagsNativeFloatPacked,
        mBytesPerPacket: fourBytesPerFloat,
        mFramesPerPacket: 1,
        mBytesPerFrame: fourBytesPerFloat,
        mChannelsPerFrame: 1,
        mBitsPerChannel: fourBytesPerFloat*eightBitsPerByte,
        mReserved: 0)

    err = AudioUnitSetProperty(toneUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Output, kInputBus, &streamFormat, UInt32(sizeof(AudioStreamBasicDescription)))
    assert(err == noErr, "error setting audiounit property!")
}

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

    do
    {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
    }
    catch
    {
        print("Audio session setCategory failed")
    }

    do
    {
        try audioSession.setPreferredSampleRate(kSampleRate)
    }
    catch
    {
        print("Audio session samplerate error")
    }

    do
    {
        try audioSession.setPreferredIOBufferDuration(0.005)
    }
    catch
    {
        print("Audio session bufferduration error")
    }

    do
    {
        try audioSession.setActive(true)
    }
    catch
    {
        print("Audio session activate failure")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for asking this question, I was looking at the same code and it saved me doing the Swift conversion myself :)

Comment: yeah I ended up using objective c for such a low-level task. I accepted that swift isn't a good choice for it.

Answer (score 0):

- `vc.theta` isn't being incremented
- `memset` only takes a byte's worth of `val`
- the AudioUnit expects `float`s, but you're storing `Int32`s
- the range of the audio data looks funny too - why not keep it in the range [-1, 1]?
- there's no need to constrain `theta` either, `sin` can do that fine.

Are you sure this used to work in objective-c?

Comment: yeah the 32767 was not meant to be there. First and last point were also nice hints^^. But memset expects an Int32, so should I even use memset for that? The objective-c code works fine. I downloaded the Xcode project from the website I mentioned above.